# js setInterval не работает после перезагрузки

Tags: javascript

Реализую "часики" на странице с использованием setInterval.
При загрузке страницы от сервера я получаю переменную serverDate (с использованием вебсокета, эту часть кода я опущу). Упрощенно код выглядит так:

```
 var intervalTask;
 onload = function(){
//
       incrementTimeAndDisply();
//
 }
       function incrementTimeAndDisply() {
           clearInterval(intervalTask);
           intervalTask =  setInterval(function () {
               serverDate = Number(serverDate)+Number(1000);
               setCurDate();//в функции меняю отображение часов на странице 
           }, 1000);
       }
```

При первой загрузке страницы работает во всех браузерах, часы тикают. После перезагрузки по f5 работает только в фаерфокс. js знаю плохо, куда копать не знаю. Как заставить это работать и после перезагрузки?

Comment: Может быть что-то переопределяет `window.onload`? Посмотрите в сторону [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: колхозным дебагом с помощью алертов я установил, что до setInterval доходит и дальше идет, но сам setInterval не выполняется. Загружается еще как то странно, сначалаалерты проходят, а потом остальная страница прогружается

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал менять `serverDate`. `setInterval` приходит "примерно" раз в 1000мс.

Получаем `serverDate` и сразу запомним только разницу:
`dateOffset = Date.now() - serverDate`.

Делаем функцию `const getServerDate = () =>  Date.now() - dateOffset`.

`setInterval` не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, Попробую завтра. А как тогда без сет интервала обновлять часы на странице?

Comment: Чтоб обновлять часы, может и нужен, а для вычисления времени -- точнее с dateOffset.

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация была такая, что сам счетчик оказывается отрабатывал, но ServerDate почему то получалось в предыдущем отображении, а потом происходил перезагрузка страницы и ServerDate был undefined (причем на одних браузерах от ServerDate приходил после перезагрузки а у других до). Изменил механизм получения ServerDate.

Comment: можно еще дельту в localStorage сохратять. И начальная дельта -- 0